# Binary to DNA encoding

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, binary

I have an 8 bit binary sequence. I need to encode this 8 bit binary sequence into DNA sequence.

E.g., I have `10011100`, the encoding rule I'm following is,

```
A=00;T=11;G=10;C=01,
```

So I want it to be something like `GCTA`. Therefore I need 4 bit DNA sequence as result.

I need to do this for a 256 * 256 matrix where each element is an 8 bit binary sequence.

I've created the matrix using the following code

```
a=imread('C:\Users\Desktop\lena.png');
disp(a);
imshow(a);
for i=1:1:256
    for j=1:1:256
        b{i,j,1} = dec2bin(a(i,j),8);
    end
end 
disp(b)
```

Comment: "so i want 4bit DNA sequence as result", you mean "4 character", right?

Comment: yes sir...4character..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a no `for` loop approach for you.  We can actually do this in three lines.

You have the first step which is to take each 8-bit number in your image and convert it into its binary representation.  Take note that this is a 2D cell array that is the same size as the image you used for doing this conversion.  Each cell array would be the representation of the number **as a string**.

Now, all you really need to do now is create a lookup, then use this lookup to generate four characters per location in a new 2D cell array.  As such, I would use the [`containers.Map()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) class to create a key-value lookup where each pair of bits gets mapped to a single character.  Once we do this, we can then use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and iterate over each 8 character string in your cell array, break up the bits into 2 element strings, and use these as keys into our lookup.  We will inevitably get 4 separate cells for the output, so we'll need to use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to bring it all back together.  As such, try doing this:

```
codebook = containers.Map({'00','11','10','01'},{'A','T','G','C'}); %// Lookup
outputCell = cellfun(@(x) values(codebook, {x(1:2),x(3:4),x(5:6),x(7:8)}), ...
             b, 'uni', 0);
finalOutput = cellfun(@cell2mat, outputCell, 'uni', 0);
```

As an example, let's say we had this 2 x 2 matrix of cell elements:

```
b = {'11111111', '10101010'; '11001100', '00001101'}

b = 

'11111111'    '10101010'
'11001100'    '00001101'
```

Running through the above code, this is what we get:

```
finalOutput = 

'TTTT'    'GGGG'
'TATA'    'AATC'
```

Comment: thank u so much...i got exactly what i wanted...i have a doubt..i'm not able to understand the syntax of cellfun..and also why 'values' and '0' are used...

Comment: `values` obtains the values inside of your lookup.  You provide a cell array of keys, and it gives you an output for each key that you want.  `cellfun` iterates over every cell in your cell array and applies an operation to it.  In this case, we want to take your 8-character string, split it up into portions of two, then use these as keys into the dictionary.  `uni` and 0 mean that the output will **not** be a single number, but it will be a cell array of 4 elements per 8-character string.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to rayryeng's solution using a lookup table, but imho `containers.Map()` is overkill:

```
codebook = 'ACGT';
output = cellfun(@(x) codebook(bin2dec(reshape(x, 2, 4)') + 1), b, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

I don't think it gets much shorter if the input consists of "binary numbers" in the sense of 8-character 0/1-strings. `reshape` breaks the strings into 4 portions of 2 characters each, `bin2dec` transforms these into four numbers in the range 0 to 3, `codebook(... + 1)` translates these into the characters ACGT.

If the input consists of actual 8-bit binary numbers, e.g. the `uint8` data `a` that you get from reading in that Lena image, you can save the detour through 0/1-strings and use base 4 from the start:

```
output = reshape(cellstr(codebook(dec2base(a, 4) - '0' + 1)), size(a))
```

Here `dec2base(a, 4)` represents the binary numbers as 4-character strings of characters '0' to '3', `- '0'` is a trick to get numbers 0 to 3, then the lookup as before, and finally some stuff to get everything in the cell-array-of-strings format.