# Bitwise XOR operation to scramble two character matrices by generating a truth table

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to perform the `XOR` operation for four characters where each of them have a bit representation as follows:

```
 A = 00

 G = 01

 C = 10

 T = 11
```

I need to create a table that `XOR`s two characters together which gives the values for all combinations of `XOR`ing pairs of characters in the following way.

```
  XOR   A  G  C  T

   A    A  G  C  T
   G    G  A  T  C
   C    C  T  A  G
   T    T  C  G  A
```

To obtain the output, you need to convert each character into its bit representation, `XOR` the bits, then use the result and convert it back into the right character.  For example, consulting the third row and second column of the table, by `XOR`ing `C` and `G`:

```
C = 10
G = 01

C XOR G = 10 XOR 01 = 11 --> T
```

I would ultimately like to apply this rule to scrambling characters in a 5 x 5 matrix.
As an example:

```
A =  'GATT'    'AACT'    'ACAC'    'TTGA'    'GGCT'    
     'GCAC'    'TCAT'    'GTTC'    'GCCT'    'TTTA'    
     'AACG'    'GTTA'    'ACGT'    'CGTC'    'TGGA'    
     'CTAC'    'AAAA'    'GGGC'    'CCCT'    'TCGT'    
     'GTGT'    'GCGG'    'GTTT'    'TTGC'    'ATTA'


B =  'ATAC'    'AAAT'    'AGCT'    'AAGC'    'AAGT'    
     'TAGG'    'AAGT'    'ATGA'    'AAAG'    'AAGA'    
     'TAGC'    'CAGT'    'AGAT'    'GAAG'    'TCGA' 
     'GCTA'    'TTAC'    'GCCA'    'CCCC'    'TTTC'
     'CCAA'    'AGGA'    'GCAG'    'CAGC'    'TAAA'
```

I would like to generate a matrix `C` such that each element of `A` gets `XOR`ed with its corresponding element in `B`.

For example, considering the first row and first column:

```
A{1,1} XOR B{1,1} = GATT XOR ATAC = GTTG
```

How can I do this for the entire matrix?

Comment: `A=00` doesn't make sense. Maybe `A='00'` or `A=[0 0]` or something else?

Comment: Also as an example, could you tell us what would be `xor(A,G)`? What would be the output type - cell array or double array or char maybe?

Comment: I figured it out.  Basically, convert the two variables into their bit representation, `xor` each bit individually, then do a reverse lookup.

Comment: @Divakar - I figured out what the OP wanted.  I've edited the post to make it much more clear. This goes against SO policy, but this is ultimately what the OP wanted to communicate... so I figured I'd edit it for future readers. Take a look at my post, and I do welcome more efficient solutions if you have any!

Comment: @rayryeng Awesome! You are the mentalist around here (+1 on being that) ;) Well your solution looks good to me. With cell arrays, the # of efficient solutions are limited anyway.

Comment: @Divakar - ahaha thank you :) Yeah I wasn't very fond of the `arrayfun / cellfun` approach, but I couldn't see any other way around it.  This was a fun problem to solve - especially with missing information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're back for some more!

First, let's define the function `letterXOR` that takes two 4-character strings and `XOR`s both strings corresponding to that table that you have.  [Recalling from our previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323609/binary-to-dna-encoding/25328000#25328000), let's set up a lookup table where a unique two-bit string corresponds to a letter.  We can use the [`collections.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) class to help us do this.  We will also need the **inverse** lookup table using a `collections.Map` class where given a letter, we produce a two-bit string.  We need to do this as you want to convert each letter into its two bit representation, and we need the inverse lookup to do this.  After, we `XOR` the bits individually, then use the forward lookup table to get back to where we started.  As such:

```
function [out] = letterXOR(A,B)
    codebook = containers.Map({'00','11','10','01'},{'A','T','G','C'}); %// Lookup
    invCodebook = containers.Map({'A','T','G','C'},{'00','11','10','01'}); %// Inv-lookup
    lettersA = arrayfun(@(x) x, A, 'uni', 0); %// Split up each letter into a cell
    lettersB = arrayfun(@(x) x, B, 'uni', 0);

    valuesA = values(invCodebook, lettersA); %// Obtain the binary bit strings
    valuesB = values(invCodebook, lettersB);

    %// Convert each into a matrix
    valuesAMatrix = cellfun(@(x) double(x) - 48, valuesA, 'uni', 0);
    valuesBMatrix = cellfun(@(x) double(x) - 48, valuesB, 'uni', 0);

    % XOR the bits now
    XORedBits = arrayfun(@(x) bitxor(valuesAMatrix{x}, valuesBMatrix{x}), 1:numel(A), 'uni', 0);

    %// Convert each bit pair into a string
    XORedString = cellfun(@(x) char(x + 48), XORedBits, 'uni', 0);

    %// Access lookup, then concatenate as a string
    out = cellfun(@(x) codebook(x), XORedString);
```

---

Let's go through the above code slowly.  The inputs into `letterXOR` are expected to be a character array of letters that are composed of `A`, `T`, `G` and `C`.  We first define the forward and reverse lookups.  We then split up each character of the input strings `A` and `B` into a cell array of individual characters, as looking up multiple keys in your codebook requires it to be this way.  We then figure out what the bits are for each character in each string.  These bits are actually strings, and so what we need to do is convert each string of bits into an **array of numbers**.  We simply cast the string to `double` and subtract by 48, which is the ASCII code for `0`.  By converting to `double`, you'll either get 48 or 49, which is why we need to subtract with 48.

As such, each pair of bits is converted into a `1 x 2` array of bits.  We then take each `1 x 2` array of bits between `A` and `B`, use [`bitxor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html) to `XOR` the bits.  The outputs at this point are still `1 x 2` arrays.  As such, we need to convert each array into a string of bits, then use our forward lookup table to look up the character equivalent of these bits.  After this, we concatenate all of the characters together to make the final string for the output.

---

Make sure you save the above in a function called `letterXOR.m`.  Once we have this, we now simply have to use one `cellfun` call that will XOR each four-element string in your cell array and we then output our final matrix.  We will use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to do that, and the input into `arrayfun` will be a `5 x 5` matrix that is column major defined.  We do this as MATLAB can access elements in a 2D array using a single value.  This value is the column major index of the element in the matrix.  We define a vector that goes from 1 to 25, then use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to get this into the right 2D form.  The reason why we need to do this is because we want to make sure that the output matrix (which is `C` in your example) is structured in the same way.  As such:

```
ind = reshape(1:25, 5, 5); %// Define column major indices
C  = arrayfun(@(x) letterXOR(A{x},B{x}), ind, 'uni', 0); % // Get our output matrix
```

Our final output `C` is:

```
C = 

'GTTG'    'AACA'    'ATCG'    'TTAC'    'GGTA'
'CCGT'    'TCGA'    'GACC'    'GCCC'    'TTCA'
'TATT'    'TTCT'    'ATGA'    'TGTT'    'ATAA'
'TGTC'    'TTAC'    'ATTC'    'AAAG'    'AGCG'
'TGGT'    'GTAG'    'AGTC'    'GTAA'    'TTTA'
```

---

Good luck!